# Как сделать ссылку на класс в С++

Tags: c++, классы, наследование

```
class A {
    public:
    A(){cout << "A";}
}

class B : public A {
   public:
   B(){cout << "B";}
}

class C : public A {
   public:
   C(){cout << "C";}
}

int main(){
    auto Class_id = getClassOf(B);
    Class_id b;
    return 0;
}
```

Как можно реализовать функцию getClassOf? И можно ли вообще?

Comment: `using Class_id = B;`, но скорее всего Вам нужны шаблоны

Comment: А если значение надо будет поменять?

Comment: похоже Вы пытаетесь сделать фабрику.

Comment: ¿А почему бы не написать просто `B b;`? Из вопроса совершенно непонятно, где и как вам могла бы понадобится прослойка в виде `Class_id`, чем бы оно не было. Так что приводите более-менее полноценный пример использования. И заметьте, что С++ является языком со статической компиляцией и тип объекта `b` задается строго во время компиляции, а не во время выполнения.

Comment: То есть нельзя?

Comment: Если это зависит от, скажем, переменной, которую вводит юзер

Comment: Нельзя. В таком случае придется делать либо иерархию классов, наследующих от какого-то базового абстрактного типа и создавать объекты динамически (то бишь уже упомянутый паттерн фабрика), либо использовать `::std::variant` или его аналоги. ЗЫ в предыдущем комментарии "со статической компиляцией" следует читать "со статической типизацией"

Comment: Попробуй entt::meta из entt. Там вроде можно создать класс по строке типо такого: auto by_id = entt::resolve("reflected_type"_hs).ctor<int, char>()(1, 1);